# ng-animate movement of a DOM element between multiple ng-repeat'ed arrays

Tags: javascript, animation, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose:

- there are multiple objects;
- there are multiple arrays;
- arrays can reference objects;
- object can (and will) be referenced only once.

Simply put - object can "be" in one array at a time.

By "moving" particular object from one array to another, the object stays the same.

Problem is - *AngularJS* makes different DOM element for the same JS object in each of `ng-repeat`-ed arrays as the object "moves".

**Question** - given the situation, is it possible to clearly `ng-animate` this movement from one `ng-repeat` to another?

I have made a preview [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ikaruss/L6ZKy/) without this clear movement.

P.S. Someone with more reputation should add `angularjs-ng-animate` tag. :-)